# the best coefficient in a complex inequation

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a sequence of complex numbers that
$$\sum_{l=1}^{n}|z_l|=1$$
I want to find the following number
$$\inf\left\vert\sup\limits_{I\subset \mathbb{Z}_n}\sum\limits_{i\in I}z_i\right\vert$$
This arises from the third problem of CMO, 1986.

Somebody told me that the result is $1/\pi$ which should use some complex analysis. Besides, I am also interested in the example that is sufficiently close to the infimum.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/654840/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/831036/42969.